# what is the meaning of this symbolics rel ${I^.}?$

Tags: algebraic-topology

I have some confusion in symbolics

My confusion is given below and marked in red circle
[image]

What is the meaning of this symbolics $\operatorname{rel}\dot{I}$?

My attempt: I know that  $I$ represent closed interval $[0,1]$   but my confusion is  about a point  which is lie above on  $I$ and  word rel

Comment: Is the [relative homotopy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy#Relative_homotopy). Here, $\operatorname{rel } I$ is the same as "relative to $I$".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be surprised if there wouldn't be a definition in your textbook. Anyway, "rel $\dot I$" means *relative to the boundary of $I$*, i.e. *relative to $\{0,1\}$*. And this means that the homotopy $H : u * u^{-1} \simeq c \text{ rel } \dot I$ is stationary on $\{0,1\}$, i.e, that $H(i,s) = u(0) = c(0)$ for all $s \in I$ and $i = 0, 1$.